# $ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{n^5}{5^n}+\frac{1}{2^{nn^{10^{10}}}}}$ Did I do it right?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I need to find the limit of this expression:

$$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{n^5}{5^n}+\frac{1}{2^{nn^{10^{10}}}}} \implies \sqrt[n]{0 + 0 + 0} \implies 0$$

from squeeze theorem (for every $n \geq 2$ : $ n^5 < 5^n$):
$$ 0 \Longleftarrow \frac{n^5}{6^n} \leq \frac{n^5}{5^n} \leq \frac{(n+1)^5}{5^n} \implies 0$$

Every other part seams obvious. Did I do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't let the argument of the $n$-th root go to infinity while leaving the $n$ in the index of the root fixed, it has to go to infinity too (indeed, it would give you a $0^0$ indeterminate form).
The correct way is notice that
$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{n^5}{5^n}+\frac{1}{2^{nn^{10^{10}}}}}=e^{\frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{n^5}{5^n}+\frac{1}{2^{nn^{10^{10}}}}\right)}$$
And the exponent tends to $\log(1/3)$ as $n\to\infty$, to see it you can use the property of log after writing $\log\left(\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{n^5}{5^n}+\frac{1}{2^{nn^{10^{10}}}}\right)=\log\left(\frac{1}{3^n}\left(1+\frac{3^nn^5}{5^n}+\frac{3^n}{2^{nn^{10^{10}}}}\right)\right)$.

Comment: You are right. Love it, thank you!